# Can spirit warrior abilities be purged by templars

Tags: dragon-age-rpg

The book says that the spirit warriors make a pact with spirits of the fade, and get "special powers."  They can cloak themselves with "magical energy."  Later, it is also described as "mystical energy."  The book also says: "Though they are not mages, this distinction is lost on most. Templars tend to treat spirit warriors as apostates since their powers look like magic..."

Templars have the ability to "cleanse an area of ongoing magic."

Are templars able to remove the spirit warrior's effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**
would be a very solid answer as the templar ability continues:

> Master: You can cleanse an area of ongoing magic. This is a
>   major action and the concentration required is such that you
>   suffer a –2 penalty to Defense until the beginning of your next
>   turn. All ongoing **spells** within 6 yards of you, whether cast
>   by friends or foes, end immediately. **Spells** that were only
>   partially cast are also cancelled and actions previously spent
>   on casting them are wasted

The Spirit warrior ability is not a spell, it's an ability. Same could be easily applied to the adversary versions of templars and their cleansing ability.

However I can see a GM ruling the opposite, or a some sort of compromise.
I would like to direct you also to the forums of roninarmy where you can actually start a speculative discussion if that is what you like, namely the dragon age rpg section:
https://roninarmy.com/forums/5-Dragon-Age-RPG